# MYSQL query a weeks worth of data each day during a certain time range

Tags: mysql

Currently the data i grab via my query is between a date AND time range however i want to change it so it querys a date range for a time range each day and output each days results(e.g 1/1/22 to 8/1/22 FROM 16:00-18:00 each day)

MY current query is bellow if you can recommend any changes.

AND created > '2021-09-09 13:00:00' AND created <'2021-09-09 16:00:00'

Comment: MySQL's TIME() function extracts just the time of day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using MySQL [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [HOUR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) functions.

Use:

```
select col1,col2...... 
from table_name
where  date(created ) between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-08' 
and hour(created ) between '16' and '18' ;
```

[Testing fiddle with different dates used](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e483d43cbfcb82d1a6632180ea891c63)

> **Important**, DATE() and HOUR() functions don't use an index if there is one on created column.
>
> For larger data you might face serious performance issues.

Comment: Thank you this seems to be exactly what i needed, would it be possible add all of the figures from the individual days together so say i select a week date range i am met with 7 totals.